# CSS missing in the eyes of Google

Tags: css, seo, service-worker, google-search

When I load the website in a browser, it shows up correctly. However, when testing it with [search.google.com](https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly/result?id=poU7f6XKR4CqgR94HSHOsg) it shows up *without* style sheets (and thereby not passing the test to be suitable for mobile devices). I assume it is because of the service worker I am using. However, I don't know that the problem is with it?

Below is the full code of the service worker in place:

```js
const
    _           = {
        domain: 'https://matchflix.ch/',
        name: 'matchflix'
    },
    cachable    = [_.domain, 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/'],
    log         = 'ServiceWorker 1.1'
;

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    if(event.request.method !== 'GET')
        return;

    if(!event.request.referrer.startsWith(_.domain))
        return;

    if(!cachable.some(url => event.request.url.startsWith(url)))
        return;

    function versionedURL(request){
        switch(request.destination){
            case 'image':
            case 'script':
            case 'style':
                let
                    version = self.serviceWorker.scriptURL.split('?')[1]
                ;
                return new Request(request.url + '?' + version);

            
            default:
                return request;
        }
    }

    let
        internal = event.request.url.startsWith(_.domain),
        request =  internal ? versionedURL(event.request) : event.request
    ;
    event.respondWith(caches.open(_.name)
        .then(cache => fetch(request)
            .then(response => {
                console.debug(log, 'Caching', internal, response, request);

                if(internal)
                    cache.put(request, response.clone());
                
                return response;
            })
            .catch(() => cache.match(request))
        )
    );
});
```

This is how the website looks in the eyes of Google:

[image]

#### What I tried so far

1. Commenting out the registration of the service worker, did not change anything unfortunately.
2. On search.google.com I saw under more information that there was an unknown error loading the script and style sheets. Unfortunately, no further information was given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site is too slow.  The entire page, including all assets needs to load within about 5 seconds so that Googlebot doesn't give up on rendering.   I'm opening your site now and the spinner is still going after 30 seconds.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that. Where I am the site loads fast. Could the speed be dependent on the location? How can I reproduce this in my location (Switzerland)?

Comment: Could this perhaps also be a service worker issue?

Comment: I'm in the US and Googlebot does most of its crawling from there, so it needs to load quickly enough from the US.  I'd recommend using a content delivery network (CDN) that will cache your assets on edge nodes around the world and make it load quickly everywhere.

Comment: Googlebot doesn't use service workers when crawling.  Assets like CSS don't typically require service workers.  If your site does require a service worker to load the initial page view, you need to change that.

Comment: [@Stephen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1145388/stephen-ostermiller): I made an interesting discovery. When I *combine* the css scripts, https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly can load it without problems. But this does not make much sense, since all files are transferred with HTTP/3, in which case the number of files does not matter, right?

Comment: Last I heard, [Googlebot is not using HTTP3](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-not-crawling-on-http-3-yet-32545.htm).  In general, you should still be designing your site to work well over HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2 because both are still widely used.

Comment: Thanks, btw. I can't load the link you provided - but it's all in the title anyway

Comment: Here is the correct link: https://www.seroundtable.com/google-not-crawling-on-http-3-yet-32545.html